# How can I make my home PC a web server using node.js

Tags: node.js, web-services

If you have any ideas about the possibility of allow my friend to access my node.js web page by browser from her computer .. she lives out side my town i tried one method which is

```
var http = require('http'); http.createServer(function(req,  res){            res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});     res.end('It works'); }).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0'); //listening all interfaces
```

it works correctly but with the computer which locate on the same LAN network

Comment: You can achieve this using https://ngrok.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You could to configure your router to allow in route to your server port.

If you have a fix IP, you don't need more things. If your IP vary along the days, you can to configure your router to use a dynamic IP.

I use https://www.dtdns.com/, a free dynamic dns provider, to allow an external URL to access my home "server" (a Raspberry PI).

But, already, it starts at configure your router, or, also, using the tunnel listed after, by I believe configuring your modem it's more fast to access (more kb/s) than using tunnel.

Comment: While I agree with the speed, opening your router up for public consumption can be dangerous if you don't know what you're doing or understand how to configure security properly. Ideally, you should host your web page on a server that has a public IP, but it seems like he just wants someone to be able to test his application, so I don't believe opening your router for this purpose is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Better to have Linux based operating system

1. Write NodeJS app (or download ready one somewhere)
2. Install [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/download.html) - This app will reply and handle all incoming connections
3. Install [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/download) (*Free version*) - This app will make sure your NodeJS application is up and running
4. Copy your application to `/var/www/yourappname` on Linux and `~/Sites` on Mac
5. [Configure Phusion Passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Node.js-tutorial)
6. If you have fixed (static) IP-address - you're good to go. Just type your static address and port (*if different from* `:80`) into browser
7. If you have dynamic IP-address - You will need a service called Dynamic DNS, I can recommend [this one](http://dyn.com/remote-access/) but is is paid service. I'm sure after a bit of Googling you can find a free similar service

If you're doing this - first time, it may looks a bit tricky and can take a day or two. But after few server setups - you will be able to do same operations with closed eyes.